# Black screen in new install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, drivers, screen

I decided to switch Windows to Linux. So I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04. I made a bootable USB drive and installed Ubuntu on it.

After successful Ubuntu installation it says reboot your device. After rebooting about 1 minute later a purple screen appears and after another minute a black screen appears.

My computer configuration:

- Company : HP
- Ram : 4 GB
- Prosessor:and a4 vision
- Graphic card : amd radeon

Comment: I tried that solution but it not work for me

Comment: What solution have you tried (and in less than 5 minutes)? Also, when asking, you're supposed to post what you already tried in order to avoid getting the same suggestions. You can [edit] your question anytime.